# How to remove class in all input field inside a form - jquery

Tags: jquery

While i click the submit button the form will look like below with error messages:

**My Problem is when i click on clear link i need to `remove the error class in input fields` and clear the values in `messages-inline` class.**

**How can i do that using jquery.**

**Note**: there may be many fields such like password, confirm password etc... So the concept should be dynamic.

```
<form id="user-login" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/user/register?destination=node%2F1" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div id="edit-name-wrapper" class="form-item">
        <label for="edit-name">
            <span title="This field is required." class="form-required">*</span>
            E-mail: 
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-text required error" tabindex="1" value="" size="60" id="edit-name" name="name" maxlength="60">
    </div>    
    <div class="messages error messages-inline">E-mail field is required.</div>

    <input type="submit" class="form-submit" tabindex="4" value="Log in" id="edit-submit" name="op">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: jQuery's documentation is quite good: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this

```
$('input').removeClass('error');
$('.messages-inline').text('');
```

Comment: A small change.. $('.messages-inline').text('); should be  $('.messages-inline').text('');

Comment: Trying to be the fast hand, so did a maistake. Corrected it now.

Comment: I always love as well as prefer SOF professionals more than google.. thanks pal